# Mexico merchant payment processor

Tags: untagged

I'm looking for a merchant payment processor for Mexico. Something like Authorize.Net.

I need my users to stay on my website and not have to be forwarded to a third party site to process the their payments.

I've been looking for the past few months but it seems that every payment processor in Mexico works like PayPal and my users have to navigate the third party's site.

I'd like to find a gateway that's can be used behind the scenes on my server.

Comment: Try http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: No idea why this question was closed.  The entire Country of Mexico is hardly a "small geographic area", not to mention his question has nothing to do with Mexico: PayPal, and most merchant processors that support web-based payment methods are not geographically limited and offer services worldwide.  This thread is useful to everyone looking for a payment processor that offers an SDK / API.

Comment: 1) Mexico is the size of the entire western United States. 2) Time wise, this site will be making use of the gateway for years to come. 3) An international payment processor is very valuable to many developers & sys. admins in many countries were this is a problem. These are trivial and incorrect excuses to close this question. Please reopen.

Answer (score 2):

We use PayPal as our payment gateway with the [PayFlow Pro](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_payflow-pro-overview-outside) service which gets us access to an SDK, their API and other tools that we can use so that our customers never leave our registration application.  It's all done in our code.

As another poster said, you can also use the [Website Payments Pro](https://merchant.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=merchant/wp_pro) service, but I have no experience with that service so I can't really comment.

Answer (score 1):

Check out PayPal [Website Payments Pro](https://merchant.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=merchant/wp_pro).

When you settle on a payment gateway be sure to carefully review [PCI Security Standards](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/) more specifically the [Data Security Standard](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/pci_dss.shtml).